# Convert *_Ctype_float into float32 in Go

Tags: go, cgo

I am new to Go and having difficulty in converting the *_Ctype_float datatype into []float32. Is there something that I am missing? I even thought of converting *_Ctype_float into string but even that was not successful.

---

I have this C function named `predictInstance` which returns `float*`. I am calling this function from Go by

```
predictionValues := C.predictInstance(
    handle,
    (*C.float)(unsafe.Pointer(&req.FlatInput[0])),
)
```

Now when I look at the type of predictionValues it says it is `*Ctype_float`. Now I want to convert this into `[]float32`

Answer (score 1):

> I have a C function which returns a `float*` array which I wish to convert to `[]float32`. I am calling this
>   function from Go with a `float*` array argument.

---

A working example,

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

float *reverse(float *f, int len) {
    float *g = calloc(len, sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        g[i] = f[len-1-i];
    }
    return g;
}
*/
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    a := []float32{3.14159, 2.718, 1}
    r := make([]float32, len(a))
    fmt.Println("a:", a, "r:", r)
    c := C.reverse((*C.float)(&a[0]), C.int(len(a)))
    copy(r, (*[1 << 20]float32)(unsafe.Pointer(c))[:])
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(c))
    fmt.Println("a:", a, "r:", r)
}

var okCFloat = func() bool {
    if C.sizeof_float != unsafe.Sizeof(float32(0)) {
        panic("C float != Go float32")
    }
    if C.FLT_MAX != math.MaxFloat32 {
        panic("C float != Go float32")
    }
    return true
}()
```

Output:

```
a: [3.14159 2.718 1] r: [0 0 0]
a: [3.14159 2.718 1] r: [1 2.718 3.14159]
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee that `copy` is OK to use on the result of this operation involving `unsafe.Pointer`? My reading of the cgo documentation suggests it might be better to write your own C-language wrapper that does the copying.

Comment: @torek: Yes. "My reading of the cgo documentation" is too vague to understand your problem. If your comment (a question) was submitted as a question, the close reason would be: Needs details or clarity.

Comment: OK, I'm looking for documentation that says that converting the C-allocated pointer to `unsafe.Pointer(c)`, then converting that to `*[1 << 20]float32` type, won't mess with the runtime system. In particular consider two things: this phrase from the cgo documentation: *the current implementation may sometimes cause a runtime error if the contents of the C memory appear to be a Go pointer.* What if one of these `float32` values in the C memory, passed to `copy`, resembles a Go pointer? We all know they're not Go pointers (they're C `float`, which may or may not be the same as Go `float32`)

Comment: Or: what if Go's `float32` does not match C's `float`? We're told that passing a pointer to the first element of an array of `float32`s works, but not that taking a returned `*C.float` works in the other direction. I can't see why it would *not* work but we were not promised symmetry in all these transforms.

Comment: @torek: Don't take things out of context. "Note: the current implementation has a bug. While Go code is permitted to write nil or a C pointer (but not a Go pointer) to C memory, the current implementation may sometimes cause a runtime error if the contents of the C memory appear to be a Go pointer. Therefore, avoid passing uninitialized C memory to Go code if the Go code is going to store pointer values in it. Zero out the memory in C before passing it to Go." [Command cgo: Passing pointers](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers). We don't have Go code writing to C memory.

Comment: @torek: "What if Go's float32 does not match C's float?" Then we `panic`. See my revised answer.